# Why two model objects are created in the new and create function in the controller class in ruby on rails instead of using just one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controllers

Here I have a piece of code from a Controller class that I don't quite understand.

I see that a new Article object is created in the new method and is passed to the corresponding view where it is used by the form.

But I don't understand why another Article object is created in the create method with the parameter passed from the form instead of just using the same object that was instantiated in the new.

(Please note that I am new to Ruby on Rails and am coming from the object oriented world of Java ,and C++. So, I am really concerned about object referencing and stuff)

```
# GET /articles/new

  def new

    @article = Article.new

  end


  # POST /articles

  # POST /articles.json

  def create

    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article lll was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in traditional web development, HTTP is stateless. Each request starts anew. Therefore instance variables won't survive across requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that makes total sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In the new action, article is not created. It is initialized. This object is used to display the form to the user.

In create action, article object is first initialized with the user request parameters, and then saved by calling `@article.save`

The need to initialize twice is because the controller is initialized on every request and the instance variables are not available across requests.

Comment: You explained the _fundamentals_ very well. +1.

Comment: But, maybe its a little bit different in ruby or my misunderstanding but technically in other oop languages like java or C++ invoking the constructor of a class allocates memory for the object in the memory -- which can be interpreted as object creation.

Comment: object is created, but it is not saved to database.

Comment: Oh You meant the actual article. Thanks Santosh!